# jQuery UI 2 datepickers and range selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to connect 2 datepickers to allow user to choose date range.

I've created code like this:

```
$(function() {
    var dates = $("#fromDate, #toDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: new Date(2010, 2 - 1, 2),
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            var option = this.id == "fromDate" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
            dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
        }
    });
});
```

This works fine, but I get weird error:
When I select date using first input for a second that datepicker shows date from second one.
I think that onSelect functions sets somehow date based on second datepicker.

If first datepicker has date in same month as second this error isn't showing.

How to recreate this behaviour:

- Select '2010-02-05' in first datepicker (after You click on date for a second month and year field change to month and year from second datepicker)

This is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/TyQSG/1/

How should I change `onSelect` function to remove this bug?

Comment: What you want exactly... will you explan by example..

Comment: I would like to remove that date change after I select date. Right now if datepickers have different months/years error that I describe is visible

Comment: take a look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range for a more efficient implementation

Comment: @helmus - the same error. Pick one date in first datepicker and try to pick in second datepicker with another month/year. For a second after selection month combobox will show month from first picker

Comment: yes i see that now, that's pretty weird ! :s

Comment: Maybe this is error in datepicker not in my code :) But it is weird, especially that it is in code on official page.

Comment: Even on Jquery [Example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range) do the same

Comment: @AlexBall - so this isn't bug in my code :) Hmm...I'm wondering how to fix this. Probably had to change something in datepicker code :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't solve the fact that they clearly have a bug in the datepicker code, but it's a work around.

If you set the [showAnim](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-showAnim) to empty then there won't be any animation and the date from the previous calendar won't show:

```
 showAnim:"",
```

Comment: This line is needed to range dates. If You pick first date (from date) then second (to date) must be bigger. This line sets minDate of maxDate for second (second one from array) datepicker.

Comment: This work around works like it should! :) Thanks for this quick fix. This don't changes the fact that datepicker has a bug

Answer (score 7):

Please check this. I think this is what you want?

Changed your code as per UI example.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#fromDate" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: new Date(2010, 2 - 1, 2),
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#toDate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $( "#toDate" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: new Date(2010, 2 - 1, 2),
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#fromDate" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});​
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TyQSG/32/)**

Comment: @Vins -  I get the same behaviour. My range code works fine, but my question is about bug that shows when 2 dates are in other months. This is also present in Your code

Comment: I'm sorry I'm unable to get your problem. Can you please please explain it once again in detail.

Comment: Open this link: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/TyQSG/1/ when You click inside first input popup with calendar shows, on top it has 2 dropdown lists-one for months and one for years. First is set to "Feb" second to "2010". Now click on any date from calendar. As You click those 2 dropdowns change their values. Date in input is selected correct so this is more of visual bug. Hope You'll understand my pour English description :)