# How to restrict the user to select dates from two datepickers in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

i am having two date-pickers options 
1) on click of image
2) on click of input box

suppose in input box date is 16-05-2014, now onclick of one image i am opening a datepicker there i need to restrict the user from selecting the old dates,

like upto 15-05-2014 days i need make disable.

```
$(function() {
    $("#travel_date").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
      changeYear: true,
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths:[1,2],
      minDate: new Date(),
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#return_on" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    }).attr('readonly','readonly');
    if($("#travel_date").val() == ""){
      $("#travel_date").val($.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy", new Date()));
    }
 $("#return_date").datepicker({
    buttonImage: "/assetsweb/plus.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    //title: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: 'both',
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    setDate: new Date(),
    numberOfMonths:[1,2],
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
     $('#return_on').val(dateText); 
     $('#modify_search_form').submit();
     // $("#return_date").datepicker("option","tDate", selected)
    }
  });
});
```

In input box date is coming selected from previous page and now if i will click on image simple date picker is coming without disable dates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI 2 datepickers and range selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901224/jquery-ui-2-datepickers-and-range-selection)

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901224/jquery-ui-2-datepickers-and-range-selection

Comment: mine one in onclick of image not on input box.

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: @abhitalks in input field date is coming from the previous page ok (eg: 05-05-2014) and now on result page one image is there. onclick of that image datepicker will come there i want dates after 15-05-2014 onwards. before 15-05-2014 all dates should disable.

Comment: you are not getting it. the concept remains the same. please take some time and try to understand what's going on there in the code.

Comment: @abhitalks on result page if directly i will click on image then all the dates will come.but if first i will click on input box(selected date 15-05-2014) and then click on image then before 15-05-2014 dates will disable...

Comment: I've attempted to explain thru an answer, but would request you to read the official docs ( [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) ), understand the concepts and then attempt to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the initial date is coming from previous page.

What you can do is:

1. Show that date with a `datepicker`, but keep it disabled so that the user doesn't change it accidentally.
2. Hook up a `datepicker` to your second date input with the image button.
3. Specify the `minDate` as the date returned by the `datepicker` of the first date input.

*HTML Example*:

```
<!-- This input holds the date coming from previous page -->
<input id="oldDate" value="2014-05-16" disabled="disabled" />


<!-- This input holds the new date which is selected by user -->
<input id="newDate" />
```

*JQuery Code Example*:

```
// Attach datepicker to the input which holds the date from previous page
$("#oldDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });

// Attach datepicker to the second date input
$("#newDate").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "... your image...",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: $("#oldDate").datepicker("getDate") // set it to date returned by first dp
});
```

*Demo*: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/D69e9/

Hope that is enough to provide you with some direction on how to get this going.